# BibTeX not working with \input or \include

Tags: bibtex, input, include

I need some help with BibTeX. I use a seperate `*.bib` file which is working perfectly, but when the commands `\input` or `\include` are used to input text from another `*.tex` file the application tells me there are suddenly undefined resources. What is happening. I have tried running BibTeX on the aux-file created by the `\include` command.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,norsk, twoside,11pt, titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{babel,textcomp}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{title}
\author{A}

\begin{document}

\cite{bibentry}

%\include{file}
%\input{file(.tex)}

\newpage
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{bibl}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I disagree on the close.

Comment: literally one of the first google results for this issue and no answer... wow...

Comment: "This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area" -- Disagree.