# How can I use \input and \include with biblatex (biber backend)?

Tags: biblatex, input, include

I have a document with external files. The only reason I am using external files is to make it easier to organize my large project. I have taken a small piece of the larger project and attempted to give a concise overview of the problem. I have found similar queries, but they have not adequately addressed the issue. The two that I found:

1. [BibTeX not working with \input or \include](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78034/bibtex-not-working-with-input-or-include) (closed)
2. [Including a .bib file with \input does not work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67968/including-a-bib-file-with-input-does-not-work)

Normally I would create a nice single piece of code to add below. In this case, however, it would defeat the purpose of the question. I have included 3 pieces below—the main document, the included document (arbitrarily using \input or \include), and the bibliography file.

When typesetting with TeX Live 2012, I receive the following error message:

> Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }.
>
> ^^I\input{"Argument of Expert Opinion.tex"}

UPDATE: There are two problems with the code below:

1. quotes need to be preceded by \string e.g. \string"file name with spaces.tex\string" (huge thanks to David Carlisle below!)
2. The slide with \parencite{Reed2007} did not have any text (besides the environments) see comments below.

**Main Document:**

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\usetheme{Berlin}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size=\normalsize}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\newenvironment{conclusion}{\begin{block}<2->{Schluss}}{\end{block}}

% Bibliography Stuff
\usepackage{csquotes}%must be before babel
\usepackage[german]{babel}%the bibliography locale must be before biblatex
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{german}{german-apa}%after biblatex, important
\addbibresource{./bibexport.bib}%needs .bib extension, location of bib file

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{premise}{O{}}{%
% Start code with optional #1
\begin{block}
<2->{Ansatz #1}
}{%
%  End code with optional #1
\end{block}
}

\begin{document}
        
\section{Schema der Argumenten}
    \input{"Argument of Expert Opinion.tex"}

\section{Bibliography}
    \begin{frame}
        \printbibliography
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Slide for include: (Argument of Expert Opinion.tex)**

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Scheme for Argument from Expert Opinion}
    \begin{premise}[Major Premise]
        Quelle E ist ein Sachkenner in Fach F, der sich Aussage A befasst
    \end{premise}
    \begin{premise}[Minor Premise]
        E behauptet, dass Aussage A (in Fach F) wahr ist (oder nicht wahr)
    \end{premise}
    \begin{conclusion}
        A ist möglicherweise wahr (oder nicht wahr)
    \end{conclusion}
    \parencite{Reed2007}
\end{frame}
```

**Bibliography: (bibexport.bib)**

```
@article{Reed2007,
author = {Reed, Chris and Walton, Douglas},
title = {{Argumentation Schemes in Dialogue}},
year = {2007},
pages = {1--11},
month = oct
}
```

Comment: Don't use quotes around the file names. Don't use spaces in the file names.

Comment: Can you please explain what `\section{Bibliography}` and `\input{"Bibliography.tex"}` should do? Printing your bibliography? Then just use `\printbibliography`. You want to display the content of `bibliography.tex`? Then use package `listings`... or clarify what you mean ...

Comment: Ah yes, the \input{"Bibliography.tex"} just has a slide with \printbibliography on it. I guess there is a 4th file. In this example, it is a redundancy, but in the larger projects, it may be quite nice to have it separate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a babel language that gives `"` a special shorthand meaning which is confusing `\input`. It is simplest not to use spaces in file names then you can just remove `"`

```
\input{"Bibliography.tex"}
```

should be simply

```
\input{Bibliography}
```

If you must use spaces in file names for some reason then you can probably do

```
\input{\string"Argument of Expert Opinion.tex\string"}
```

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, however I am getting another error. Patching footnotes failed. Footnote detection will not work. Argumentation Referat.aux:50: Undefined control sequence. And by the way, I love spaces in filenames.

Comment: OK that means the problem in this question is solved and the files are being input but there is an error in one of the files. The site works best if new questions are asked as separate questions rather than in comments. Please make a small example that generates that error and ask a new question (I can't guess given the fragments of code posted in this question)

Comment: Thank you for your help, especially for the tip with \string"! I am not going to open a new question related to this one, as I do not think the following problem constitutes such an action: The problem was that I did not have text before \parencite{Reed2007}. After adding some text, it compiled fine (unsure exactly why) For any viewers in the future, I hope this helps you too!